how to apply custom sld to wms layer in layer call(sld_body parameter).I tried but defaullt style only applied not the style i send through sld_body
const sld = ` <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
        xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
        xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <NamedLayer>
            <Name>SLISG:zone_boundary</Name>
            <UserStyle>
                <Title>SLISG:zone_boundary</Title>
                <FeatureTypeStyle>
                    <Rule>
                        <PolygonSymbolizer>
                            <Stroke>
                                <CssParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
                            </Stroke>
                        </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    </Rule>
                </FeatureTypeStyle>
            </UserStyle>
        </NamedLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescriptor>`;

    const wmsLayerOptions = {
      format: 'image/png',
      name: "Circle",
      pane: "group3",
      minZoom: "10",
      group: "Cadastral",
      showOnSelector: true,
      visible: true,
      maxZoom: "22",
      lname: "Circle_Cadastral",
      transparent: true,
      styles: '', 
      sld_body:sld
    };      
    wmslay`er = new (L as any).tileLayer.wms(layer.url,wmsLayerOptions);
    mapObj.addLayer(wmslayer);

I want the style i write in sld should apply to the layer``

Did you read and try the answers to the question I closed your last one with https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193460/http-wms-getmap-using-default-sld-instead-of-provided-one

Yaa i tried. That's why i have given workspace:layername in my sld . Stil default style  applied.
anything should modify in layer publishing or anything to add in sld to make it default

see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/227750/79

SLD is applied when i remove workspace from layer name in  tag. I just give  layername instead of worspace:layername.
